# Term for words or phrases signifying change in numeric quantities?

Tags: computational-linguistics, linguistic-typology

Phrase like "take away", "more than" ,"times" imply certain mathematical change (subtract,add,divide etc.) in the quantity in current context. For eg.

`The number of girls "exceeds" the number of boys in the class.`

Is there a term to categorize such words/phrases which have mathematical significance?

Comment: "imply certain mathematical change" — perhaps, "relation/comparison", not "change"? If so, [Comparative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative) may be a proper term.